# How to export data with Excel?

Tags: c#, excel

From my client, I am exporting a set of details to an Excel sheet.  In these details, I have a field which is of `Date` type.  Initially, the number format for this date field was `"dd-mmm-yyyy"`.

Now, I changed it to `"Date"` (just to see if it works).  After exporting these details to Excel, I enter values in Excel.  In this date field, say, `"Forecasted Date"`, I enter the date.  Now I try to update the data in my client by reading in the Excel sheet.

Suppose the Excel data is in the dataset `oDSExcelData`.  In the process of updating, I am creating a temporary table.  I am creating a dataset which has the schema of this temporary table.  Let's say that this dataset is `oDsTemporarytable`.  In `oDsTemporarytable` the column "Forecasted Date" is of date type datatype.  In `oDsExcelData`, the data type of `"Forecasted Date"` is string.  It was supposed to be of `Date` type.

Due to this, when I try to merge these 2 datasets, I get an exception saying

> Mismatch in data type.  Datetime is expected.

I think the problem begins while reading from Excel.  How can I get the datetype field from Excel?

Comment: I take it you are using OLEDB providers. I had this problem a while back. The only way that i could solve my problem was to use [Linq to CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Willem.Let me try this